# GitHub client revert/rollback changes?

Tags: git, github

In Git i wanted to create a patch **without** /a and /b. I found that `git diff cdeab78 62a91a1 --no-prefix > patch.txt` was working. But before i tried something else i don't know exactly.

But now if i go in my Github client (MAC) and i look at 'Changes' i see a whole list of changes and files /b/... On the command line if i do `git status` i see:

```
Untracked files:   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

b/
```

What is this? And how do i role it back? What do i have to do? I **didn't** 'Commit and Sync' those changes yet to my remote repo on GitHub.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you created a directory named `b`. You can check the content and if it is not needed (created by mistake), you can just remove it, using: `rm -fR b`